# Create Multiple dataframes from a large text file

Tags: python

Using Python, how do I break a text file into data frames where every 84 rows is a new, different dataframe? The first column x_ft is the same value every 84 rows then increments up by 5 ft for the next 84 rows. I need each identical x_ft value and corresponding values in the row for the other two columns (depth_ft and vel_ft_s) to be in the new dataframe too.
My text file is formatted like this:

```
   x_ft     depth_ft    vel_ft_s
0   270     3535.755    551.735107
1   270     3534.555    551.735107
2   270     3533.355    551.735107
3   270     3532.155    551.735107
4   270     3530.955    551.735107
.
.
33848   2280    3471.334    1093.897339
33849   2280    3470.134    1102.685547
33850   2280    3468.934    1113.144287
33851   2280    3467.734    1123.937134
```

I have tried many, many different ways but keep running into errors and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: can you read the whole text file into memory or is it too big?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into [pandas.read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html), which automatically outputs a DataFrame. Once doing so, you can isolate the rows of the DataFrame that you are looking to separate (every 84 rows) by doing something like this:

```
df = #Read txt datatable with Pandas
arr = []
#This gives you an array of all x values in your dataset
for x in range(0,403):
    val = 270+5*x
    arr.append(val)

#This generates csv files for every row with a specific x_ft value with its corresponding columns (depth_ft and vel_ft_s)
for x_value in arr:
    tempdf = df[(df['x_ft'])] = x_value
    tempdf.to_csv("df"+x_value+".csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can get indexes to split your data:

```
rows = 84
datasets = round(len(data)/rows) # total datasets
index_list = []

for index in data.index:
    x = index % rows    
    if x == 0:
        index_list.append(index)

print(index_list)
```

So, split original dataset by indexes:

```
l_mod = index_list + [max(index_list)+1]
dfs_list = [data.iloc[l_mod[n]:l_mod[n+1]] for n in range(len(l_mod)-1)]

print(len(dfs_list))
```

Outputs

```
print(type(dfs_list[1]))
# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

print(len(dfs_list[0]))
# 84
```